# Spring rest junit post with json

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, junit

I am trying to working with project to create junit test for the spring rest webservice. This work fine with the get method but it did works with the post json as input. Here is the code with get method. if anyone help with rest post json junit testing it will appreciated.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations=("/spring/application-config.xml"))
public class LoginServiceFacadeTestImpl extends AbstractTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }


    @Test
    public void testSearchProductByNameFound() throws Exception {
        String keyword = "";
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/perlogin")
            .param("q", keyword)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value(keyword));
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error as follows

```java
Time elapsed: 5.477 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$5.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:549)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:141)
    at com.db.mybank.backend.services.presentation.impl.test.LoginServiceFacadeTestImpl.testSearchProductByNameFound(LoginServiceFacadeTestImpl.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

Here is my controller class

```java
package com.backend.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class JSONController {

    @Autowired
    private SessionManager sessionManager;

    public JSONController() {
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/perlogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ValDataVo preLogin(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        addDefaultResponseHeaders(httpServletResponse);     
        sessionManager.setHttpSession(httpServletRequest.getSession());
        logger.info("***login session*****::"+httpServletRequest.getSession().getId());

        return resultData;
    }
}
```

Here is my dispatcher servlet

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>     
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.backend.controller" />

</beans>
```

Comment: You're getting a 404. Can we see your mvc configuration?

Comment: from the stack trace, it seems that the exception was thrown in another test method, would you please review your question?

Comment: Ohhh i just change the name of the test while editing the question

Comment: I reverted back the function name...

Comment: Your web.xml is not involved. Remove it. Then post the contents of `/spring/application-config.xml`. Or is that what you've already posted?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations=("/spring/application-config.xml"))
```

refers to the XML configuration you've shown, there are no `@Controller` beans registered and therefore nothing to handle any requests.

Your `@ContextConfiguration` should probably be loading the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file which is used by the `DispatcherServlet`. That context configuration file should contain

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to register any found `@Controller` beans as handlers.

Comment: sorry i didnt updated the @controller class and the dispatcher servlet and i edited my question

Comment: @ramesh027 Is `/spring/application-config.xml` the your dispatcher servlet config? If it isn't, switch it.

Answer (score 0):

So the component scanner is picking up your Controller.

**See if this works for you:**

My approach uses Jackson to JSon encode an object and POST's the Rest service with Json directly. The controller has a utility designed to retrieve the body containing the Json from the HttpServlettRequest. There are other ways to do that I know.

**My Test**

```
package com.myproject.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.myproject.domain.Element;
import com.myproject.model.DbBrokerModel;
import com.myproject.rest.PostJsonRestTest;

// Not sure if you need any of this for your test so just delete it if you don't 
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={
        "classpath:usermgmt.properties",
        "classpath:ldap.properties",
        "classpath:jdbc.properties",
        "classpath:email.properties"
})
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/conf/applicationContext-email.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/conf/applicationContext-jdbc.xml"

})
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class PostJsonRestTest {


    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PostJsonRestTest.class);


    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private PostJsonRest jsonRest;


    // TODO @Inject or @Autowired anything you may need 


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.ctx).build();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }


    /**
     * <b>triggerJsonPostTest</b><br/>
     * Explain what you are doing
     * 
     */
    @Test
    public void triggerJsonPostTest() {


        //Set up the model to be converted to Json
        TestModel requestModel = new TestModel();


        // Build the Model object and stuff them with test data
        List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
        requestModel.setElementId("123");
        requestModel.setElementType("change");
        requestModel.setElementsAffected(3);
        requestModel.setChanges(elements);



        try {
            //Convert the Test Model To JSon
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            byte[] requestJson =  objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(requestModel);

            //Call your rest contoller 
            MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/test/receive-json")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(requestJson))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())             
                    .andReturn();
            //TODO Wrtie a bunch of validation for the return OBJECT
            //TODO: Remember to test for positive and negative results in seperate @Test's 


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

**My Rest Controller**
So I am receiving Json in the HttpServlettRequest so you will see a utility method to retrieve the body from the request. You may or may not get any use out of it but its here for the purposes of my example.

```
package com.myproject.rest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

/**
 * <b>PostJsonRest</b><br/>
 * Rest Controller Example
 * @author dhargis
 *
 *
 */
@Controller
public class PostJsonRest {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PostJsonRest.class);


    //TODO You may want to @Inject or @Autowire something here 

    /**
     * <b>receivePostJSon</b><br/>
     * Listens for properly formated JSon formated request of object type TestModel
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/trigger/receive-json", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
    public void receivePostJSon(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

        String body = "";
        try{
            //See below utility class 
            body =  getBody(request);

            //TODO You may want to log something here 

        }
        catch(IOException e){

            log.warn("Error: Problems parsing incoming JSON request  ", e);

        }

        finally{


        }

        // TODO REMOVE Temporary Output to the command line before deployment
        System.out.println(body);

    }

    /**
     * <b>getBody</b><br/>
     * This little utility class will give you the body containing the JSON
     * @param request
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */

    private String getBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        String body = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                    stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("Error while reading the request body", ex);
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    log.error("Error while closing the reading for request body", ex);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        body = stringBuilder.toString();
        return body;
    }

}
```

Hope that helps good luck.